# ¿Como arreglo este metodo para mostrarme los nombres indicandole un limite?

Tags: java, string, lista, estructuras-de-datos, vscode

Buenos dias tengo un problemas de estructura de datos con listas enlazadas y es que tengo un programa donde se ingresar nombres, muestra la lista y otra opcion donde se ingresa un valor y este va a hacer el limite de caracteres donde guardan los datos de nombres menores a estos: ejm ingreso un nombre juan 4 caracteres, luego digo que el limite va a hacer 3 entonces juan no se puede guardar en la lista y se borraria, luego ingreso carlos 6 caracters y le digo que el limite va hacer 8 entonces lo guarda en la lista. la verdad nose como resolverlo. aqui dejo mi codigo, el problema esta en el metodo cantidad de caracteres en la opcion 3

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;

  public class Ejercicio1 {     

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Listas lista = new Listas();

    try {
        lista.opciones();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e);
    }
  }
}

class Nodos{

    public Nodos siguiente; // puntero
    public String nombres;

    public Nodos(String nombres) { // constructor para insertar al final
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.siguiente = null;
    }

    public Nodos(String nombres, Nodos siguiente) { // constructor para insertar el inicio
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
     }
    
  }


class Listas {
    
    Nodos inicio;
    protected Nodos fin; // punteros para saber donde esta el incio y fin

    public Listas() {
        inicio = null;
        fin = null;
    }

    public void opciones() throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Listas lista = new Listas();
        int opcion;

        do {

            System.out.println("\n" + "Seleccione alguna de las opciones:" + "\n" + "1. Ingresar un nombre. " + "\n"
                    + "2. Imprimir lista. " + "\n" + "3. Eliminar nombres que pasan de ciertos caracteres. " + "\n"
                    + "4. Salir. ");
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre a la lista");
                    String nombreIngresar = br.readLine();
                    lista.ingresarNombre(nombreIngresar);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("La lista ingresada es:");
                    lista.mostrarLista();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del limite de caracteres ");
                    int valorLimite = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    lista.CantidadCaracteres(valorLimite);

                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcion no seleccionada correctamente...");
                    break;

            }
        } while (opcion != 4);
    }
    
    public void ingresarNombre(String nombres) {
        inicio = new Nodos(nombres, inicio);
        if (fin == null) {
            fin = inicio;
        }
    }
    
    public void mostrarLista() {
        Nodos recorrer = inicio;
        while (recorrer != null) {
            System.out.println("[" + recorrer.nombres + "]----> ");
            recorrer = recorrer.siguiente;
        }
    }

    
    
    public void CantidadCaracteres(int valorLimite) {

        /*Nodos recorrer = inicio;
        while (recorrer != null) {
            if (recorrer.nombres.length() <= valorLimite) {
                //recorrer = recorrer.siguiente;
                System.out.println("good way");
        } else {
            System.out.println("bad");
            }
            
        }¨
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Entonces hay que borrar los nodos que tengan un nombre con un largo mayor a un valor X , pero al ingresar no importa el largo del nombre?

Comment: CantidadCaracteres funciona se actualizas recorrer después del if-Else recorrer = recorrer.siguiente pero no borra los nodos

Comment: "Entonces hay que borrar los nodos que tengan un nombre con un largo mayor a un valor X , pero al ingresar no importa el largo del nombre?" , no importa el largo del nombre, quiero que se borren los nombres que tengan nombre con un largo mayor a un valor X, CantidadCaracteres es el metodo que toca arreglar pero se me queda en un bucle infinito, necesito ayuda con eso, y no se como resolverlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idealmente tendrías que crear un método para borrar nodos sin importar la ubicación y otro para recorrer y buscar los nodos que cumplen con la condición buscada (en este caso puse todo junto).

Para borrar tienes que considerar todos los casos posibles donde puede haber nodos a borrar

1. Lista vacía: no implemente este caso porque depende de lo que quieras hacer ( a tu lista le falta el método esVacia() ).
2. Borrar el primer nodo. (evaluar si es el único o no) es necesario actualizar la referencia original 'inicio' y si es único también 'fin'
3. Eliminar un nodo intermedio
4. Eliminar el nodo final lo que implica actualizar la referencia original 'fin'

El paso a paso de cada caso está en los comentarios en el código.

Utilice dos referencias una para nodo previo y otra para nodo actual (en el cual se evalúa el largo de la palabra)previo es útil cuando hay que borrar un nodo intermedio.

Igualmente hace pruebas para verificar que funcione, agrega el método en el case 3 y luego agregá *mostrarLista()* para ver el resultado

```
    public void borrarSiMayor(int valor) {
    Nodos frente = inicio;
    Nodos previo = inicio;
    Nodos temp = null;
    while( frente != null) {
        if(frente.nombres.length() > valor) {
            // es el nodo inicial  un solo elemento
            if(frente == previo) {
                if(frente.siguiente == null) // si hay un solo elemento actualizo fin a null
                    fin = null;
                frente = frente.siguiente;  // actualizo frente (proximo nodo o null)
                inicio = frente;            // actualizo el inicio original
                previo = frente;            // actualizo previo
            }else { 
                // es un nodo intermedio
                if(frente.siguiente != null) {
                    temp = frente;                       // copio el nodo a borrar
                    previo.siguiente = frente.siguiente; // enlaza dos nodos evitando el intermedio
                    frente = frente.siguiente;           // actuallizo frente
                    temp = null;                         // temp = null
                }else {
                    // es el nodo final
                    fin = previo;                        // actualizo la referencia original de fin
                    previo.siguiente = frente.siguiente; // siguiente de anterior es null
                    frente = frente.siguiente;           // frente == null
                }                   
            }// fin de los casos donde hay que borrar
        }else {
            // en caso que no haya que borrar hay que pasar a siguiente nodo
            previo = frente;
            frente = frente.siguiente;
        }// fin del condicion largo de palabra
        
    }// fin del while
}
```

Hice algunos cambios en mostrarLista() no son necesarios pero me ayudaron a visualizar mejor la lista

```
    public void mostrarLista() {
    Nodos recorrer = inicio; 
    while (recorrer != null) { 
        System.out.print("[ " +recorrer.nombres + " ] -> "); 
        recorrer =recorrer.siguiente; 
    }
    System.out.println(recorrer);
}
```